# Shortcut for locking the screen or launching a screensaver on OS X

Tags: macos

Is there a shortcut that I can use in order to trigger a lock screen or maybe at least a screen saver?

Comment: There's a forum covering this information http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090831093941225. Isn't there something that you can do with Spaces to move the mouse to the corner of the screen to kick in the screensaver?

Comment: [Is there a quick way to lock my Mac? - Apple - Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64/is-there-a-quick-way-to-lock-my-mac/15492#15492)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift + Ctrl + Eject puts the display (only the display, not the whole computer) to sleep and will then prompt you for a password if you have enabled "Require password [amount of time] after sleep or screen saver begins" under System Preferences > Security